# BIRT Mathematics on data set

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

I am pretty new to Birt reporting, i can make simple charts and tables, bet when it comes to some calculation of values from data sets - i have no clue in which direction should i watch.

For example i have this simple data set:

```
count1   count2   max   type   lenght
616      3858     21    STEEL    20
723      4432     14    STEEL    40
854      5869     21     ALL     20
838      5225     14     ALL     40
```

And i would like to have Birt to calculate approximately this:

```
SUM(count2)/SUM(count1) WHERE  type=ALL
```

so this

```
((5869+5225)/(854+838))
```

My question would be how could i get there. At this point i think i would need just the right direction how these kind of operations could be made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [Computed Column](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[birt]+computed+column)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to display this value somewhere on the report, like at the bottom of a table where this data is presented.  If this is the case then add an aggregation data element to the footer of the table where the data is displayed.  In the aggregation data element you will have the opportunity to specify an expression SUM(count2) and a filter condition [type=ALL].  You can then do the division in another data element.

If you want to simply compute the value you described you you could do it with SQL, i.e. SELECT SUM(count2)/SUM(count1) FROM myTable WHERE type='ALL'. You would have to provide the data to the report as a data source which could be in the form of an excel spreadsheet, *.csv, database connection, etc.

So there are a few ways to do this depending on what your requirements are.